# TextField cannot dismiss keyboard when put to multiline

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

When the `TextField` is created like this

```
 TextField(
            "Describe...",
            text: $text,
            axis: .vertical
        )
        .focused(focused, equals: .prompt)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .lineLimit(2...)
        .modifier(ClearButton(text: $text))
        .submitLabel(.done)
        .onSubmit { hideKeyboard()
            print("test")
        }
```

When the keyboard done button is pressed, it creates a new line instead. I don't want any new lines in the `TextField` at all.

[`.submitLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/submitlabel(_:)) is supposed to do it. So I added but it doesn't.

Next I tried creating a [`.onSubmit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/onsubmit(of:_:)) callback, that doesn't work either. In fact, "test" is never printed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not because of the multiline of the textField, but because of the axis. If you remove the linelimit the problem remains, but if you change the axis the textfield now "works" (it is not multiline). The same thing happens if you use a `TextEditor`. However, if you want a multiline textField with the ability to dismiss the keyboard a user-friendly solution could be adding a toolbar. Now the user will interpret the textField as a multiline textField(because of the return button) and have the option to disable the textField.

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    enum Field {
        case prompt
    }
    
    @FocusState var focus: Field?
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                TextField(
                    "Describe...",
                    text: $text,
                    axis: .vertical
                )
                .focused($focus, equals: .prompt)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .lineLimit(2...)
                .submitLabel(.return) // <- change to return
                .toolbar { // adding the toolbar
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                            Spacer()
                            Button("Done") {
                                focus = nil
                            }
                    }
                }
           
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [short post](https://danielsaidi.com/blog/2023/09/15/how-to-dismiss-a-multiline-swiftui-textfield-by-pressing-the-return-key) on how to use `FocusState` and `onChange` to simulate a return key press in a multiline `TextField` or `TextEditor`:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    @State
    var text = ""

    @FocusState
    var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter text", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
            .submitLabel(.done)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                guard isFocused else { return }
                guard newValue.contains("\n") else { return }
                isFocused = false
                text = newValue.replacing("\n", with: "")
            }
    }
}
```

You can extract these modifiers into a custom `ViewModifier` to make it easy to reuse it:

```swift
struct MultilineSubmitViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    init(
        text: Binding<String>,
        submitLabel: SubmitLabel,
        onSubmit: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self._text = text
        self.submitLabel = submitLabel
        self.onSubmit = onSubmit
    }
    
    @Binding
    private var text: String
    private let submitLabel: SubmitLabel
    private let onSubmit: () -> Void
    
    @FocusState
    private var isFocused: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .focused($isFocused)
            .submitLabel(submitLabel)
            .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                guard isFocused else { return }
                guard newValue.contains("\n") else { return }
                isFocused = false
                text = newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
                onSubmit()
            }
    }
}
```

You can also create a custom view extension to make it even easier to use:

```swift
public extension View {
    
    func onMultilineSubmit(
        in text: Binding<String>,
        submitLabel: SubmitLabel = .done,
        action: @escaping () -> Void
    ) -> some View {
        self.modifier(
            MultilineSubmitViewModifier(
                text: text,
                submitLabel: submitLabel,
                onSubmit: action
            )
        )
    }
}
```